# jQuery plugin to style objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I've been looking at the various JavaScript UI libraries and am wondering if there's one that can add some styling to page elements. I'm currently adding rounded corners, shadows, borders, and gradients via my own CSS + hacks to get it working on IE.

I'm using jQuery for a number of tasks and wondered if there's a plugin that can add these design flairs more easily to DIVs. Not that you want to go overboard with this stuff, but when you need to use it, you'd like to depend on cross-browser and tried-and-tested solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check out the [jquery ui themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). It's got a common set of styles that you can use to achieve some of the effects you want.

One I use quite a bit is the [dropshadow plugin](http://dropshadow.webvex.limebits.com/) and another is [jquery corner](http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner-demo.html)